# How can a pass an array value or <option> value to a SQL query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a function calls in my HTML that creates a new mysql table containing a list of tables and populates them into the options's element.  I then need to populate another select statement "onselect" or "onchange" of one of the options, but I can't figure out how to pass the value of the selected option to a variable in a sql query. I can only get it work by manually assigning a value to the variable.

It might be easier to use:

```
var option_user_selection = element.options[ whatever they select ].text
```

But then I can't figure out how to right THAT query loop.

URL: http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~pjnodin/assg/index.php

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        SQL Query Builder
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="content-container">
    <div id="data-sets"  title="Click on a Data Set">
        <h3>
            Data Sets
        </h3>
        <form name="myForm">
            <select size="34" style="width: 200px" id="selectBox1" name="dataSets" onChange="optionBlockRecipe2(this.selectedIndex)">

            <?php
                prepareTableList();
                optionBlockRecipe();
            ?>

            </select>
            <input type='hidden' id='myhidden' value=''>
    </div>
    <div id="attributes" title="Click on an Attribute">
        <h3>
            Attributes
        </h3>
            <select size="34" style="width: 200px" id="selectBox2" name="attributes" onClick="alert(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)">
                <?php
                                        optionBlockRecipe2();
                ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php
function prepareTableList()
{
mysql_query("drop table Table_List");
mysql_query("drop table TheJoins");

$rs = mysql_query("SHOW tables");

mysql_query("create table Table_List(
    TableName char(20) not null,
    TableEnglish char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(TableName))");

mysql_query("create table TheJoins
    (Table1 char(20) not null
    ,Table2 char(20) not null
    ,TheJoin char(50)
    ,primary key(Table1,Table2))");


for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $rs); $i++)
{
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_row( $rs );
    mysql_query("INSERT into Table_List(TableName) VALUES('$tmp[0]')");
    //print("<OPTION value=\"$tmp[0]:$tmp[0]\">$tmp[0]</OPTION>\n");
}
}

function optionBlockRecipe()
{
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT TableName FROM Table_List");
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $rs); $i++)
{
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_row( $rs );
    print("<OPTION value=\"$tmp[0]\" selected=\"selected\">$tmp[0]</OPTION>\n");
}
}
function optionBlockRecipe2()
{
    $temp = Orders;
$rs = mysql_query("DESCRIBE '$temp'");
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $rs); $i++)
{
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_row( $rs );
    print("<OPTION value=\"$tmp[0]:$tmp[1]\" selected=\"selected\">$tmp[0]</OPTION>\n");
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `<option>` is actually not an element, but rather an attribute of the `<select>` element. This is a common misconception, and makes `<select>` perhaps the most (and maybe the only) confusing element.

The reason why they did this was to enable developers to add any number of select-able options to a list, complete with text and values, in an organized fashion.

As such, the solution to your problem is simple: When a new `option` is selected, take the `value` of the `<select>` element, instead of the `<option>`.

Also, without AJAX you are going to run into trouble, since PHP is a server-side language and not client-side, so it was not made to respond to user events, but rather server-events, like receiving a submitted form.